# What's the shortest path to simplify $\tan{85°} \tan{35°} \tan{15°}+\tan{55°} \tan{5°} \tan{75°}+2\cot{50°}$?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We have this expression:
$$\tan{85°} \cdot \tan{35°} \cdot \tan{15°}+\tan{55°} \cdot \tan{5°} \cdot \tan{75°}+2\cot{50°}$$
I want this expression to be in its simplest form.
I fed this into the Symbolab calculator but it gave a very long answer. According to my own information, I wrote it like this:
$$\cot{5°} \cdot \cot{55°} \cdot \cot{75°}+\tan{55°} \cdot \tan{5°} \cdot \tan{75°} + 2\cot{50°}=\\ \\ \frac{\cos{5°} \cdot \cos{55°} \cdot \cos{75°}}{\sin{5°} \cdot \sin{55°} \cdot \sin{75°}}+\frac{\sin{5°} \cdot \sin{55°} \cdot \sin{75°}}{\cos{5°} \cdot \cos{55°} \cdot \cos{75°}}+2\frac{\cos{50°}}{\sin{50°}}$$
And now, if: $$a=\cos{5°} \cdot \cos{55°} \cdot \cos{75°}\\b=\sin{5°} \cdot \sin{55°} \cdot \sin{75°}\\c=\cos{50°}\\d=\sin{50°}$$
It will be very long so i show my final way with the variables $a,b,c,d$:
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}+2\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a^{2}d+b^{2}d+2abd}{abd}$$
but as you see, it is also very long. I am looking for the simplest form for this expression.

Comment: Are you asking for an expression for that quantity that is as short as possible?

Comment: Yes, sir. @GregMartin

Comment: thanks. I edited. @GerryMyerson

Comment: @AmirrezaHashemi Unfortunately, it's still not quite clear. You have been given a trigonometric expression, but it's not clear what you want to do with it. I would usually guess that you wish to evaluate the expression exactly (i.e. without approximating, e.g. with a calculator), but your own attempt doesn't seem to do this, as it just introduces new variables. Are you being asked to evaluate this expression? Or is there something else we're supposed to do with it?

Comment: I have been asked to simplify this statement as much as possible. @TheoBendit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the identity $\tan(x)\cdot\tan(60°-x)\cdot\tan(60°+x)=\tan(3x)$. We now have
$$\tan5°\cdot\tan55°\cdot\tan65°=\tan15°\implies\tan5°\cdot\tan55°\cdot\tan75°=\cot65°$$

and
$$\tan25°\cdot\tan35°\cdot\tan85°=\tan75°\implies\tan15°\cdot\tan35°\cdot\tan85°=\cot25°$$

The expression now is simplified into $$\tan25°+\frac1{\tan25°}+\frac2{\tan50°}=\frac{\tan^225°+1}{\tan25°}+\frac{2}{\tan50°}$$

Using the fact that $\sin(2x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}$, we simplify as

$$\frac{\tan^225°+1}{\tan25°}+\frac{2}{\tan50°}=\frac2{\sin50°}+\frac{2\cos50°}{\sin50°}$$

From the double angle formulae,

$$\frac{2(1+\cos50°)}{\sin50°}=2\cdot\frac{2\cos^225°}{2\sin25°\cos25°}=2\tan65°$$

Therefore,$$\boxed{\tan{85°} \cdot \tan{35°} \cdot \tan{15°}+\tan{55°} \cdot \tan{5°} \cdot \tan{75°}+2\cot{50°}=2\tan65°}$$

Comment: thank you so much sir. this is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: +1: (also).  I looked at this for hours, trying unsuccessfully to find an alternative approach.